# PHP Smarty include within js function

Tags: php, javascript, smarty

I have a tooltip script I grabbed from:
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex5/fixedtooltip.htm

Normally used kind of like this:

```
<script src="http://thescript.com/tooltip.js"></script>

<a onMouseover="fixedtooltip('I am html harharhar', this, event, '150px')" onMouseout="delayhidetip()">JavaScript Kit</a>
```

BUT.. I'm using **Smarty** to parse templates.
I am trying to parse my tooltip "content" as an include file.

```
<script src="http://thescript.com/tooltip.js"></script>

<a onMouseover="fixedtooltip('{include file="popup.html" all=$response['item1'] id=$response['id']}', this, event, '150px')" onMouseout="delayhidetip()">JavaScript Kit</a>
```

Unfortinatly, I can not find a way to do this without breaking the javascript. Thoughts?

Comment: Why does this breaks the javascript? Does the file popup.html contain any quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[{literal}](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.literal.tpl) tags allow a block of data to be taken literally. This is typically used around Javascript or stylesheet blocks where {curly braces} would interfere with the template delimiter syntax. Anything within {literal}{/literal} tags is not interpreted, but displayed as-is. If you need template tags embedded in a {literal} block, consider using {ldelim}{rdelim} to escape the individual delimiters instead.

Comment: its actually because new lines interfer with javascript execution. additionally, CSS classes refrenced in the popup are also causing some kind of interference. When withdrawn to test small snippets at a time, the style property is also causing broken javascript. but thanks for your input, i didn't know about those tags.